# When does my query return null? (N highest salary question)

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+------------------------+
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
+------------------------+
```

**This solution fails**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

RETURN(
    SELECT Salary
    FROM (SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT N)  
    AS TEMP   
    ORDER BY Salary ASC LIMIT 1

  );
END
```

**Above solution did not pass this case**
[image]

[image]

**Accepted Solution:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE M INT;
  SET M = N - 1;
  RETURN(

  SELECT DISTINCT Salary FROM Employee ORDER by Salary DESC LIMIT M, 1

  );
END
```

My question is why does accepted solution can return null when there is only one value in table? Thanks

BTW, this question use MySQL 
[image]

Comment: What do you think happens if you ask for the second row of a table that has only one row?

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: Mark Rotteveel  Then my first solution should return null as well since  LIMIT 2 is not exist.

Comment: I don't think this is MySQL, I think you are using SQL Server

Comment: Sami Seriously? man

Comment: I don't think it will return `NULL` when you pass `1` value, if you pass `>1` then it will return `NULL` cause the table has only one row, cause your asking for row 2 which is not exists, so normally it will return `NULL`

Comment: @crazymind This looks like a question on LeetCode platform to me. What was the call made to the table in terms of `getNthHighestSalary()` for the test case you have given?

Comment: @crazymind mention the `@` before the name, else people won't be notified unless there are only 2 people in the conversation. Anyway, I have never seen LeetCode not showing the test case if our solution fails. It should give you the test case. Show that JSON. It will have the call data.

Comment: @ vivek_23 I have already listed the failed test case. I don't understand what is your question.

Answer (score 0):

It fails, because the subquery is always going to return a set of rows, even if there are not "n" of them.

Probably the simplest method is to use `offset`/`limit`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SET v_offset = N - 1;
    RETURN(SELECT Salary
           FROM Employee
           ORDER BY Salary DESC
           LIMIT 1 OFFSET v_offset
          );
END;
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/MGKQ41096) is a rextester showing that it works.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution did not pass this test case: {"headers": {"Employee": ["Id", "Salary"]}, "argument": 2, "rows": {"Employee": [[1, 100], [2, 100]]}}

Comment: Your output: {"headers":["getNthHighestSalary(2)"],"values":[[100]]}, Expected: {"headers":["getNthHighestSalary(2)"],"values":[[null]]}

Comment: @crazymind . . . The second highest value is 100, so I think that is correct.  If you are counting starting at 0, then you can remove the `- 1` in the answer.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Idk, the question says it returns null if there is no nth highest salary. I guess they consider 100 and 100 are both first highest in this case; therefore, no second highest salary?

Comment: @crazymind . . . The rextester has two salaries, 100 and 200. When 2 is passed, the value is 100.  That seems correct to me.

Comment: I also add "DECLARE M INT;" in your code; otherwise, it won't compile. Your solution returns 100 (suppose to be null) when you call getNthHighestSalary(2). The test case only has two 100 in the table.